# babel-plugin-transform-async-to-module-method without regenerator

Tags: javascript, async-await, bluebird, babeljs

My goal is to have async/await compiled down to Bluebird promises with minimal performance impact.

[`babel-plugin-transform-async-to-module-method`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-module-method/) appears to be the most common way to compile async/await to Bluebird, however it slows my application down by about 10-20% which is not acceptible. I suspect that muchfun of this is due to regenerator, which seems to be required for `babel-plugin-transform-async-to-module-method`.

For instance, I have this code in index.js:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

async function foo() {
    console.log('foo');
    await Promise.delay(500);
    console.log('bar');
}

foo();
```

and this package.json:

```
{
  "name": "async-regenerator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "browserify index.js -t babelify --outfile bundle.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-module-method": "^6.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.3.5"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "transform-async-to-module-method",
        {
          "module": "bluebird",
          "method": "coroutine"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Compiling that with `npm run build` does work, but then running bundle.js produces an error:

```
ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
```

Adding regenerator to package.json does fix the error:

```
{
  "name": "async-regenerator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "browserify index.js -t babelify --outfile bundle.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-module-method": "^6.7.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.7.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.6.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.3.5"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "transform-runtime",
        {
          "polyfill": false,
          "regenerator": true
        }
      ],
      [
        "transform-async-to-module-method",
        {
          "module": "bluebird",
          "method": "coroutine"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Then bundle.js does successfully run, but it makes my build 100kb larger and possibly introduces the aforementioned performance problem.

My question is, why is regenerator even required for this? My target browsers (Chrome and Firefox) support generators, so there must be some way to just use native generators, right? I don't know if that'd fix my performance problem, but I'd like to try.

I know there are a couple other similar approaches to async/await:

- [Kneden looks promising but buggy.](https://github.com/marten-de-vries/kneden/issues/13)
- [fast-async](https://github.com/MatAtBread/fast-async) seems like it's also similar to what I want, but I have some other problems running it, maybe that's a topic for another question here later :)

If I'm neglecting some other approach that you think would be good to try, please let me know.

I put the example code on https://github.com/dumbmatter/babel-async-await-regenerator - PRs are welcome!

Comment: See https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/

Comment: Seems to have the same issue, error about `regeneratorRuntime` unless I include regenerator.

Comment: async-to-generator shouldn't require regenerator runtime. Have you looked at the compiled code? Did you remove the previous plugin? What is the error message?

Comment: Error message is the same as in my original post. Here's the minimal Babel configuration: https://github.com/dumbmatter/babel-async-await-regenerator/blob/transform-async-to-generator/package.json and the bundle which clearly references regenerator https://github.com/dumbmatter/babel-async-await-regenerator/blob/transform-async-to-generator/bundle.js

Comment: The problem is that the es2015 preset still transforms the generators, and that uses the regeneratorRuntime. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [async-to-generator](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/) plugin for this. But unfortunately the es2015 preset will still transform generators, so you will have to modify the es2015 preset. You could use [`modify-babel-preset`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modify-babel-preset), or just simply unfold the preset in your babel config.

```
"babel": {
  "plugins": [    
    "transform-es2015-template-literals",
    "transform-es2015-literals",
    "transform-es2015-function-name",
    "transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
    "transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions",
    "transform-es2015-classes",
    "transform-es2015-object-super",
    "transform-es2015-shorthand-properties",
    "transform-es2015-duplicate-keys",
    "transform-es2015-computed-properties",
    "transform-es2015-for-of",
    "transform-es2015-sticky-regex",
    "transform-es2015-unicode-regex",
    "check-es2015-constants",
    "transform-es2015-spread",
    "transform-es2015-parameters",
    "transform-es2015-destructuring",
    "transform-es2015-block-scoping",
    "transform-es2015-typeof-symbol",
    "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",

    "transform-async-to-generator"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. For some reason I was thinking the preset would run first, leave async/await in place, and then the plugin would run after that and transform the async/awaits. Guess my mental model of babel is not quite right :) And this is significantly faster than regenerator, although still a bit slower than not using async/await at all.